# Tool for Creating Polygons

Tags: polygon-creation

Does anyone know of any tools that exist for creating a polygons.

I need to provide some employees with the ability to create shapes that detail the boundary of certain locations. So I just want a simple tool that they will simply be able to use to create polygons. (I'll then let them import the points to my main application).

(It wouldn't take a massive amount of work to create this myself in Google Maps, but would love if that could be avoided and something already exists).

---

**Update with more information:** (Sorry for missing out obvious key points).

The main application is very basic. It's really just a frontend to a vacation rental portal that allows travellers to search for locations and then return properties within or around that location. I use a mix of tools to do the searching PostGIS and Solr with spatial search depending on the actual module as the backend changes...

What happens is, I take a location search string, and then attempt to find the best matching WOEID (using Yahoo GeoPlanet) for that location string. At the moment, we've got about 200k different polygons coords which have been assigned to their respective WOEID. The shapes are then drawn on as a polygon to a single Google Map and it's used to help travellers visualize there search boundaries.

Because we have now exhausted  of the available shape files that I can find to easily match up against WOEIDs (such as flickr dataset), we are going to start manually creating the polygons and assign them to each WOEID.

So I'm just looking for a tool that I can set up our employees with to create the polygons. I realise that they won't be perfect, but this is really only for visualization. So it's not important that they are perfect..

Comment: What GIS software do you use ? don't answer just add the tag so that other users can see

Comment: It would be useful, when you ask your question a bit more precise. Do you have any experience with GIS? What is your 'main application'? Are you looking for a open source solution?

Comment: @StefanB. Sorry I missed out with the extra information. I've added the extra information. (And yes something Open Source. I can probably develop what I need my self in a day. So it's not a major problem) I hope i've been clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this geo json editor](http://geojson.io/).  You can convert to whatever format you need once you have all the polygons drawn out.

The UI is really great -- drag and drop a file into a modern browser.

Comment: This is the perfect answer. Thanks. Can't upvote you because I only have 1 score. (Strange that my Stackexchange profile wasn't merged from the other stackexchange sites)

Answer (score 1):

I Assume open layers will be perfect for you, you should check it out:
here is the main progect page:
openlayers.org

here is what I believe you are looking for:
http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Feature/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.geometry

here is example:
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-features.html